# How to fix vertical panel text and indicator plugins in Xubuntu 16.04

Tags: xubuntu, xfce, taskbar

I've been using Ubuntu with Xfce for years and I love it.

However, a recent update (I suppose) has broken the text orientation (that used to be vertical but is now horizontal) on my vertical taskbar/panel. I'd like to make the text vertical again (see picture, only the taskbar is relevant).

[image: Look to the left, the firefox text, the rest is irrelevant]

In addition, the wi-fi indicator plugin does not appear anymore unless my computer connects automatically to an internet box on startup. Generally this is okay, but it makes things a bit annoying when I bring my computer someplace new (I have to save my panel configuration, put the default one, click on the wi-fi indicator to connect and remember the connection, load my previous panel, then restart or do it all over again if ever I have to reconfigure that connection or reconnect).

Thank you for the support !

Answer (score 2):

What worked for me: changing the **Mode** of the panel to `Deskbar` (from the other modes available: `Horizontal` and `Vertical`).

System: Xubuntu 16.04.1